# Button starts as active

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I have a few buttons that change the information in an IFrame. I have it to where the buttons change class styles when they are clicked to show their active, but was wondering how I would make the button show active to start out...

```js
< script language = "JavaScript"
type = "text/javascript" >
  var nl;
var al;

function CngClass(obj) {
  if (nl) nl.className = '';
  obj.className = 'selected';
  nl = obj;
}

function CngClass2(obj) {
  if (al) al.className = '';
  obj.className = 'selected';
  al = obj;
} < /script>
```

```css
<style> body {
  margin: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #cccccc;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 62px;
  height: 20px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fd5a1e;
  background-color: #000000;
  display: block;
  width: 62px;
  height: 20px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.txt10 {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, verdana;
}
.txt11 {
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, verdana;
}
.txt12 {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, verdana;
}
.txt16 {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, verdana;
}
.white {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.pad3 {
  padding-left: 3px;
}
.border {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
.border1 {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #fd5a1e;
}
.btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 62px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.selected {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #fd5a1e;
  width: 62px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #fd5a1e;
}
</style>
```

```html
<table border "0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:500px; background-color:#cccccc">
  <tr>
    <td class="txt12 bold" colspan="4" align="center">National League</td>
    <td class="txt12 bold" colspan="4" align="center">American League</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="txt11 btn"><a onclick="CngClass(this);" href="nwest.html" target="national">West</a>
    </td>
    <td class="txt11 btn"><a onclick="CngClass(this);" href="ncentral.html" target="national">Central</a>
    </td>
    <td class="txt11 btn"><a onclick="CngClass(this);" href="neast.html" target="national">East</a>
    </td>
    <td class="txt11 btn"><a onclick="CngClass(this);" href="nwild.html" target="national">Wild</a>
    </td>
    <td class="txt11 btn"><a onclick="CngClass2(this);" href="awest.html" target="american">West</a>
    </td>
    <td class="txt11 btn"><a onclick="CngClass2(this);" href="acentral.html" target="american">Central</a>
    </td>
    <td class="txt11 btn"><a onclick="CngClass2(this);" href="aeast.html" target="american">East</a>
    </td>
    <td class="txt11 btn"><a onclick="CngClass2(this);" href="awild.html" target="american">Wild</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
      <iframe src="nwest.html" name="national" frameborder="0" height="165" width="250">You need a Frames Capable browser to view this content.</iframe>
    </td>
    <td colspan="4">
      <iframe src="awest.html" name="american" frameborder="0" height="165" width="250">You need a Frames Capable browser to view this content.</iframe>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <td colspan="8" class="txt10" style="background-color:#cccccc; width:500px; height:25px;">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;z-best record &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; x-playoff team &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; w-wild card team
  </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: on all of them or just one ? just add the class to the html.

Comment: Just the buttons that are linked to the pages that load in the IFrame to start. I tried putting the selected class in the html but when I click the other buttons I want that class to revert to the regular button class

Comment: Right, give me a mo to add this to my comp to muck around. back in 5

Comment: I can't quite understand the `if (al) al.className = '';` and the  `al = obj;`. I see you are initilizing the vars at the top but what for ?

Comment: When I was looking around that was code that I found that worked the way I needed it too.. wasnt completely sure what everything did on it but I changed some things around and it countinued to work... Here is the website where it is... http://jcampos021.angelfire.com/standings/standings.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my god, What a nightmare that was, so much for back in 5. Too much hassle trying to format the code of the above answer after an edit, Change your html back the way it was and change the JS to this.

```js
  var nl;
var al;
var Alinks = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
function CngClass(obj) { 
   
    for(var i=0;i < Alinks.length;i++){ 
     if(Alinks[i].getAttribute('target')=="national"){
       if(Alinks[i].className="selected"){     
             Alinks[i].className="";
    }
   }
  }
  if (nl) nl.className = '';
  obj.className = 'selected';
  nl = obj;
}

function CngClass2(obj) {
 
 for(var i=0;i < Alinks.length;i++){ 
     if(Alinks[i].getAttribute('target')=="american"){
       if(Alinks[i].className="selected"){     
             Alinks[i].className="";
    }
   }
  }
  if (al) al.className = '';
  obj.className = 'selected';
  al = obj;
}
```

Comment: nice, thanks... I have been trying to re-learn all this stuff since I haven't been playing with it in a long time. So my last question about it is, my IFrame loads nwest.html as default, is there a way to make is so that when my parent page loads the west button is in active style and when you click another button it goes back to regular style? hope I explained that better...

Answer (score 0):

Try this see if it's o.k,changed it a bit. Didn't see why you neede 2 functions so I changed it to one. Consider adding some of them inline styles to the css. There probably is a better way but this should do it. ### EDITED, forgot to add starting classes...

```js
function CngClass(obj,targ) {
 
 var Alinks = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
 var topboxes=document.getElementsByClassName('txt12');
 for(var j=0;j<topboxes.length;j++){
  topboxes[j].style.backgroundColor="#cccccc";
 }
 for(var i=0;i < Alinks.length;i++){
  console.log(Alinks[i].className);
  if(Alinks[i].className="selected"){Alinks[i].className="";
  }
 }
console.log(obj+' '+targ);
obj.className="selected";

document.getElementById(targ).style.backgroundColor="orange";
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #cccccc;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 62px;
  height: 20px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fd5a1e;
  background-color: #000000;
  display: block;
  width: 62px;
  height: 20px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.txt10 {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, verdana;
}
.txt11 {
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, verdana;
}
.txt12 {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, verdana;
}
.txt16 {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, verdana;
}
.white {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.pad3 {
  padding-left: 3px;
}
.border {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
.border1 {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #fd5a1e;
}
.btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 62px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.selected {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #fd5a1e;
  width: 62px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #fd5a1e;
}
```

```html
<table border "0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:500px; background-color:#cccccc">
  <tr>
    <td class="txt12 bold" colspan="4" align="center" id="national">National League</td>
    <td class="txt12 bold" colspan="4" align="center"id="american">American League</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="txt11 btn"><a onclick="CngClass(this,this.target)" class="selected" href="nwest.html" target="national">West</a>
    </td>
    <td class="txt11 btn"><a onclick="CngClass(this,this.target)" href="ncentral.html" target="national">Central</a>
    </td>
    <td class="txt11 btn"><a onclick="CngClass(this,this.target)" href="neast.html" target="national">East</a>
    </td>
    <td class="txt11 btn"><a onclick="CngClass(this,this.target)" href="nwild.html" target="national">Wild</a>
    </td>
    <td class="txt11 btn"><a onclick="CngClass(this,this.target)" class="selected" href="awest.html" target="american">West</a>
    </td>
    <td class="txt11 btn"><a onclick="CngClass(this,this.target)" href="acentral.html" target="american">Central</a>
    </td>
    <td class="txt11 btn"><a onclick="CngClass(this,this.target)" href="aeast.html" target="american">East</a>
    </td>
    <td class="txt11 btn"><a onclick="CngClass(this,this.target)" href="awild.html" target="american">Wild</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
      <iframe src="nwest.html" name="national" frameborder="0" height="165" width="250">You need a Frames Capable browser to view this content.</iframe>
    </td>
    <td colspan="4">
      <iframe src="awest.html" name="american" frameborder="0" height="165" width="250">You need a Frames Capable browser to view this content.</iframe>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <td colspan="8" class="txt10" style="background-color:#cccccc; width:500px; height:25px;">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;z-best record &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; x-playoff team &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; w-wild card team
  </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: I had the two functions there to work the buttons on the two separate tables... I might have to try some inline styles in my a tags like you suggested, maybe some javascript that can change those styles when buttons are pressed and not... Thank you for your help

Comment: give us a mo, i'll redo it. Just noticed aswell that bttom class doesn't stay selected. Give me 5